# i want to make a web site which is able to control a hardware on a clients computer

Tags: c#, web, hardware, hyperterminal

- running test on local host, the website coded with c#, is able to connect to the comm port and pass commands to the hardware just as done by hyperterminal software
- if this website is uploaded/hosted this will not work, as the server doesnot have this harware connected to the comm port needed.

  one way is to ask the hosting company to set up a special computer for me with the hardware drivers etc.

  not possible.

  - - defining hardware, the hardware is a remote control car.

so what is the solution?

Comment: no, 136 answers. you must be hving an idea if possible and how right?

Comment: plz check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478344/controlling-a-hardware-connected-to-a-com-port  for clear problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a Silverlight Out of Browser application which can run with elevated rights.
Perhaps it is possible to access the COM Port with ActiveX, too. But that would be a Internet Explorer only solution.

I found this blog where someone managed to get that working.

http://tech-michael.blogspot.com/2009/12/silverlight-talking-to-arduino.html

Comment: plz check  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478344/controlling-a-hardware-connected-to-a-com-port