# controlling a hardware connected to a com port

Tags: c#, asp.net, hardware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [i want to make a web site which is able to control a hardware on a clients computer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478164/i-want-to-make-a-web-site-which-is-able-to-control-a-hardware-on-a-clients-comput)

- the the hardware for example be a simple gsm modem

this is a general question, for asking of methods and opinions as for the following

- control this hardware using the computer the hardware is connected to.
- control this hardware using another computer over a network
- control this hardware using a web site application or a simple web site

the thing to consider --> this is a class group project which we implement in c# asp.net.

### edit

hope the broadness is narrowed down.

assume there is a remote control attached to the comm port of my computer, which controls a small car.

i want user around the world to be able to move the car using there keyboard.

i can write a desktop app to control the remote using the printer port but thats on my local host only.

get the point
/?

thanku

Comment: You are asking a number of very braod questions. What are your thoughts about each of the points you mention? If you can present some of your own thinking people can add to that.

Comment: Edit the original question instead of asking a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The task you want to do sounds similar to the following http://www.lss.hr/RCcar/en/documentation.html although they have implemented it using PHP, JavaScript and C. The source code and documentation is available which should provide you with a good starting point.

The code to control the car on the  server side will be similar to that of desktop app you would just send commands to the car when a user clicks a link on the web page.